# Appium server limitation

Tags: node.js, appium

Why does Appium server have the limitation of working on only one device per session? Specially since appium essentially runs on node.js which has no such limitation.

Comment: Have you tried AWS device farm ? You can run in cloud your test in multidevices

Comment: Atually bootstrap port is the main cause. If u want to run multiple sessions you can use appium grid

Comment: I understand the workarounds with using device farms. In fact I have setup a device farm internally. The reason I am asking this is to understand the reason for this limitation. Mostly because as per my understanding of node.js I don't really see a logic behind this limitation.